# Why python not returns None?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class tree :

    def __init__(self):

        self.val=0
        self.right=None
        self.left=None

def create_tree():

    x=input()

    if x==-1:
        return None

    root=tree()
    root.val=x

    print(root)
    print(root.val)
    print(root.right)
    print(root.left)



    while(True):
        print ("reach1")
        root.left=create_tree()
        root.right=create_tree()
        print("reach2")
        break


    return root

def main():

    root=tree()
    root=create_tree()

main()
```

Why None is not returned when x==-1 in create_tree() ?

sample output:

```
2 <__main__.tree object at 0x7f58cbf11128> 2 None None reach1
-1 <__main__.tree object at 0x7f58cbf11208>
-1 None None reach1
```

Comment: Becasue `-1 != '-1'`

Answer (score 8):

> Why None is not returned when x==-1 in create_tree() ?

Because `input()` returns a **string** from `stdin` input. 
`input` reads a line from input, converts it to a **string** and returns that.

You can check this using `type` operator.

```
type_of = type(x)
>> string
```

The solution is to compare what you've entered with `"-1"`

```
if x == "-1":
    return None
```

or just use `int` method.

```
x = int(input())
if x == -1:
    return None
```

Comment: @IshaanKalsi, if you find that this answers your question, I encourage you to press the green check mark.